# Windows Phone XNA message box error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, xna

I have two methods in my windows phone app and both of them display a message box.
I can call method1 as many times as I like and the messagebox always displays correctly.  However, if I then call method2 having previously called method1, 
I get the error:

```
the Guide UI is already active. Wait until Guide.IsVisible is false before issuing this call
```

Both of my methods look like this;

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Guide.BeginShowMessageBox("Error",
    "There was a problem.",
    new List<string> { "OK" }, 0, MessageBoxIcon.Alert, asyncResult => Guide.EndShowMessageBox(asyncResult), null);
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this?
I thought my call to EndShowMessageBox should be enough but I am still getting the error.

Comment: Can you show the stuff inside the try block. Hard to tell a problem in code without the code causing the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue.  My code was actually causing the messagebox to open twice very quickly.  I simply added a check to IsVisible and now the second box does not display.

```
if (!Guide.IsVisible)
```